# Do something after return statement - Java

Tags: java, soap

The requirement is below.

I have a Electrical chargeable vehicle (device) which communicates to a java application (service) via SOAP message. When the device is switched on, It sends a request to the service through SOAP message.

The service receives the SOAP message request and checks whether the device is authorized device (we check this from database where we have few authorized devices details stored) or not. If the device is authorized, then the service respond to the device via Accepted or Rejected SOAP message.

When the service sends the SOAP response to the device, after 5 SECONDS, the service has to send a SOAP request to the device asking the device settings.

Below is the sample code from the service.

```
public AuthorizeResponse authorize(AuthorizeRequest parameters) {
   AuthorizeResponse authorizeResponse = new AuthorizeResponse();

   //check from db whether the device is authorized or not from 
    parameters.getDeviceName();

   return authorizeResponse; 
}
```

Now, the requirement is, after "return authorizeResponse;", I have to do Thread.sleep(5000) and send a request from the service to the device.

Can anybody help me in this regard how to do?

Comment: Look into aspect oriented programming for sh*ts and giggles.

Comment: This smells like a classic example of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You my friend are looking at solving the wrong question entirely. Instead tell us why you think that this is a requirement, and we'll show you why it in fact isn't.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a [`finally` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

```
public Integer printAfterReturn() {
    try {
        int a = 10;
        return a + 10;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("printed");
    }
}
```